# BlackBerry consume wcf

Tags: blackberry, java-me, network-programming

I am working with OS 5.0 and I am trying to get some info from a wcf.
On the emulator it works like a champ, but on a device, with wifi connected, I get the error:

> APN is not specified

my code:

```
    HttpConnection con = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        final int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println(responseCode);
        }
        is = con.openInputStream();
        byte[] responseData = new byte[10000];
        int length = 0;
        StringBuffer rawResponse = new StringBuffer();
        while (-1 != (length = is.read(responseData))) {
            rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length));
        }
        final String result = rawResponse.toString();
        _labelField.setText(result);

    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        _labelField.setText(ex.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
            con.close();
            con = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to read about BlackBerry network information like [Network Transports](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Network-Transports/ta-p/482457), [Network Transports 2](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742)

Comment: thx for the links, still need to look the video. But, u see an error on my code or is something particular with that smartphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article ["Different ways to make HTTP Socket Connection"](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0). This article would help you understand how to make network connections if you are on BES network or BIS or WiFi or 3G network etc.

Getting back to your problem, if you want to connect through Wi-Fi, you will need to modify your connection url. Replace the following:

> con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

With this:

> con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi");

Now it would work on device with Wi-Fi connectivity.